# How to optimize large database?

Tags: database, record, keyword, article

I am going to build a system that has the number of `article` increases everyday. Every `article` has some `keyword`, every `keyword` can belong to some `article`. My current database look like this:

```
**Article**(ID, Title, Content, ...)
**Keyword**(ID, Value, ...)
**Xref_Article_Keyword**(ArticleID, KeywordID)
```

It works fine but I afraid that the number of articles and keywords be larger, then it will take a lot of time to query. For example: List all article by a keyword or list all keyword of an article.

So, are there any solution (both software and hardware) to optimize the queries?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Relational database systems like MySQL or PostGresql are able to index tables, which gives efficient retrieval time even for billion of rows.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: No worthwhile experience with databases. I am not talking about queries, but about the way you will store your database*

Have you thought of [indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) your database? This way you can index your data at various time or amount-of-data based intervals. For example, you can update the database index
 at midnight every day, or per 1000 new entries.

If you direct queries to the index first, then the result space would be limited to only the records satisfying your index. This may also be useful in case you want more than one (sorted) results, which (to me) translates to almost all cases.

---

I personally think that unless you are going for some bleeding edge data mining or for very high scalability, you should heed to @Basile Starynkevitch's advice.